# Restore Git repository

Tags: repository, git

I don't know if git related questions can be asked here but if it can be asked then I have a silly question. Inside a folder, I added some files did git init, then committed it and then added it to git hub. Now I used rm -rf .git so now the two are disconnected and I want to connect the repository on GitHub to the one on my laptop. I know I can create a new repository I just want to learn how to do this. Also, I am very new to git so please tolerate my mistakes. Btw I use Ubuntu 19.10.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If there are sites where I can ask this question please suggest I will be thankful to you.

Comment: If you already pushed to github, you can clone it from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you deleted your entire local repo:

Go you your git project on Github. (I'm using `gitignore` for demonstration purposes) Find the green "Clone or download" button.
[image]

Copy the url from the dialog.
In your terminal: `git clone [your repo address]`
[image]
and `cd [repo name]` into it.